# From ViewController to TabBarController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

My initial VC is the LoginController. After the login a seque is going to a tabbar. This works fine but what I want is to check if the user is logged in to present the tabbar.
I put   `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabBar" sender:self];`
 in LoginController inside the viewdidAppear but is not nice because it shows the LoginView for a while. If put it inside the viewDidLoad is not working.
Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: i dont get it. if you are not planning to show some kind of login screen, why use a viewcontroller for the login?

Comment: I will use the LoginViewController only when the user is logged out.

Comment: have you tried calling the segue from viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear then?

Comment: I am getting this error : Warning: Attempt to present <TabBarController: 0x75c2f50> on <LoginViewController: 0x719ed00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!